# Finding the point on the real axis collinear with $i$ and $-1+2i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $A = i$ and $B = -1+2i$ be two points on the complex plane. Find the point $D$ on the $x$-axis such that $A$, $B$ and $D$ are collinear.

I don't know from where to start, and what does "$D$ is on the $x$-axis" signify?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? What does A(i) and B(-1+2i) mean? Without context it's hard to know what "D is on the x-axis" means, but a guess is the real axis. Also, please read [this page about formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) and [this page about homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348)

Answer (score 1):

That $D$ lies on the $x$-axis implies that the [ordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinate) of $D$ is $0$.

So, we can assume $D$ to be of the form $(a,0)$ with $a$ real.

Do you know how to calculate the area of a triangle given all the three co-ordinates?

Now, for collinearity, the area is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $A$ as the point $(0,1)$ and $B$ as the point $(-1,2)$. Write down the equation of the straight line passing through these points. Put $y=0$ in that equation and solve for $x$, because any point on the $x$-axis is of the form $(a,0)$.

Comment: thats it thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you see, then complex numbers can be represented as points on the $x \;y$ plane. So, your points are $A(0,1)$ and $B(-1,2)$. Can't you now use your regular coordinate geometry?